# How to interpret the outcome of the scatterplot

Tags: r, data-visualization, scatterplot

I wanted to see what is the relation between two variables using scatterplot in r. The outcome can be seen as below. My question is how to interpret this plot. Yes, the two variables are highly correlated, but how to interpret the points(light circles) in the right upper corner of the plot? does that mean that some of the points in one variable doesn't correlate with some points in the other variable?

[image: scatter plot of two variables]

Comment: It just means that your data is less dense at extreme values.

Comment: The regular heteroscedasticity and the positivity of the values indicate a log-log scatterplot will be revelatory: try it.  Even better, construct a log-log scatterplot of $y/x$ *versus* $x.$